# Shape to TopoJSON - wrong projection

Tags: topojson

Anyone out thee have a solution?

Using a TopoJSON file that has been converted from Shape. In QGIS, when I open it, it has no projection? I can't reproject a TopJSON file in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

As of RFC7946 all GeoJSON - and I guess by extension all TopoJSON - MUST be in WGS84 long-lat coordinates: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946

QGIS will assume this for anything with a missing CRS. I can reproject it to anything once its loaded into QGIS.

If your TopoJSON *isn't* WGS 84 (CRS:84) then it is non-compliant and you'll have to work out what it is and assign that yourself.

Comment: Must is too strong word. Other coordinate systems are allowed but RFC7946 does not tell how they should be expressed. Section "Positions" in the TopoJSON specification also mention projected coordinate reference systems https://github.com/topojson/topojson-specification.

Comment: thanks - Nope not working.  I have no problem converting and projecting to geoJSON but not a projected topoJSON and QGIS will not reproject to topoJSON format. the diffence between the 2 is size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740705/difference-between-geojson-and-topojson

Comment: Got a topoJSON file to line up with other data using FME - shape to TopoJSON LL84. However, TopoJSON format is used in Power BI and it will only handle 50K records and I have 840K records!